# How to add a width to expand the following text in a table

Tags: php, css

I have the following text and I would like to know if there is a way to add a width to make the desktop version to take up most of my td cell width?

I tried to add a width but can't make it expand but then I have it as white-space: wrap. If I get rid of the wrap then it does work but I can't get it to break up into the next line:

This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__. '/header2.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid']))
{
    header("Location: index.php?practice_diary_view=notlogin");
    exit();
}
else
{
    include_once __DIR__. '/includes/dbh.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id = ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
    {
      echo "SQL error";
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_SESSION['u_id']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $last_name = $row['last_name'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM practice_diary WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2))
        {
            echo "SQL error";
        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $first_name, $last_name);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

            if($resultCheck2 < 1)
            {
                echo '<div class="nopracticediaryview">There are no practice diary records associated with this user</div>';
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<table class="practice_diary_view">
                <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="update_title">Welcome to the Practice Diary Viewing Section</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>';

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
                {
                    echo '<tr>
                    <th>Username:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['user_uid']),'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['first_name']),'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Last Name:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['last_name']),'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Lesson Title:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['lesson_title']),'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Describe Lesson:</th><td class="describe_lesson">',htmlspecialchars($row2['describe_lesson']),'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Hours of Practice:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['hours_practice']),'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Date of Practice:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['date_practice']),'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }

                echo '</table>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.practice_diary_view .describe_lesson
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding min-width with precentage to the TR and not the TD

Comment: I am confused here, so why do we need to add to the tr instead of the td because the text is in the td area?

Comment: I tried to do this but still can't get it to work.. Can I add a class in the td, can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: <tr class="describe_lesson">
                      <th>Describe Lesson:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['describe_lesson']),'</td>
                      </tr>

Comment: I really need to get this to work guys but would also appreciate if you could let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: yea just do it with plain html. you can even copy the output from the chrome devtools

Comment: but shouldn't this be the same as in doing it in php?

Comment: it is just easier to do it in php because I can loop through

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if the html you posted is the one from the table, it seems a bit broken.
You set up a table with 3 columns: on the first row you span the first cell onto the other 2, but then in your while loop you only consider 2 cells instead of 3. You might want to reduce your colspan to 2 or otherwise, if you need it to be 3, you might want to add a colspan 2 on your second column of each row. This should make the width span on the entire table width.
I am also a bit worried about the **tr** that you are opening right before the while (and not closing or using anywhere after): try and remove it.
Therefore you don't need to prevent white-space from wrapping, you need to remove it.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out and I got rid of the opening tr tag but still can't get the width to work in my td if I used the pre-wrap

Comment: I still can't seem to get the text to expand the full td cell and would appreciate if someone can tell me if this can be done

Comment: Indeed it can be done. May i ask you to post the actual html you are using now? So i can identify the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I am still need some help here and I will post the html

Comment: I can't post the html because I did the table all in php instead as shown above but still wondering whether it is possible to expand the width... I don't know why the width does not respond in my table format

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: Yeah, you can post the php code that generates the html too, it's the same to me.